# MySQL, using columns in another table for a CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, an **Items** table that looks like this:

---

**Items**

```
Item       Count
-----------------
1          20
2          24
3          49
```

And a table called **ItemsConfig** that looks like this:

---

**ItemsConfig**

```
ItemCountLow    ItemCountHigh    ItemCountStatus
------------------------------------------------
0               20               Low
21              50               Normal
51              100              Surplus
```

What I would like to do is build a query that will compare item counts in the **Items** table using the `ItemCountLow` and `ItemCountHigh` thresholds in the **ItemsConfig** table, to derive the **ItemCountStatus**.

Here are the create statements for each of these tables

**Items table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Items` (
  `Item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Count` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Items`
--

INSERT INTO `Items` (`Item`, `Count`) VALUES
(1, 20),
(2, 24),
(3, 49);
```

**ItemsConfig table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ItemsConfig` (
  `ItemCountLow` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemCountHigh` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ItemCountStatus` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ItemsConfig`
--

INSERT INTO `ItemsConfig` (`ItemCountLow`, `ItemCountHigh`, `ItemCountStatus`) VALUES
(0, 20, 'Low'),
(21, 50, 'Normal'),
(51, 100, 'Surplus');
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT item, count, 
CASE
    WHEN count > ItemsConfig.ItemCountLow AND count < ItemsConfig.ItemCountHigh  
        THEN ItemsConfig.ItemCountStatus
END as 'status'
FROM Items
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT i.item, i.count, ifnull(ic.ItemCountStatus,'Unknown') status
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN ItemsConfig ic on (i.count between ic.ItemCountLow  AND ic.ItemCountHigh)
```

Comment: I would suggest a `LEFT JOIN` in case the `count` exceeds any of the limits in `ItemsCount`. Here, I was working on this demo.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83b549/3

Comment: I added a "unknown" status to the query which shows when the join criteria is false.